# The first view of the switch is different from the active-passive view

Tags: android, maui

The first view of the switch is different from the active-passive view. This is the case as seen in the image. I want it to look like the second image at first. How can I do it?
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKZv3.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTHrz.png)

Comment: Show me your code + this tag <Style TargetType="Switch"> from your styles.xaml.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mthnzbk/3f2f784f18cf86b408ca264df289c946

Comment: Replace the color white, with something else, in the link you gave me.

Comment: <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray400}" /> This?

Comment: No, You have this line there:  <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource White}" /> , replace the White with your gray color.

Comment: This is line 3 in the file. Not sure why they ship the template with that white color. If you do not set it in the styles, when you move your mouse over them, you will see how they are getting painted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't apply the style that you shared, the problem you said will indeed arise.

And there is a known issue about this, you can follow it up here: [Android Switch view has inconsistent colors when "off"](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7673).

But as a workaround, you can set property `ThumbColor`(not `White` color) for your Switch.

For example:

```
  <Switch  IsToggled="False"  ThumbColor="Gray"></Switch>
```